# Is it possible to develop windows phone 8.0/8.1 applications using the windows phone 7.1 sdk

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I'm using Windows 7 and don not want to migrate to windows 8. I also want to develop Windows Phone applications. But Windows 8 SDK requires Windows 8. So Windows Phone SDK 7.1 can develop applications for Windows 8 or Windows 8.1 Phones.

Comment: If you can install a second disk drive in your computer, I suggest getting an SSD and installing Windows 8.1 Professional on it to make a dual-boot system.

Answer (score 1):

You can develop Windows Phone 7.1 apps that will run on Windows Phone 8/8.1 devices. But you'll only be able to use features available in the Windows Phone 7.1 SDK.

Answer (score 0):

You can not develop apps for Windows Phone 8/8.1 using Windows Phone  7.1 SDK. And to dvelop for Windows Phone 8.1/Windows 8.1 you need to have a Windows 8.1 installation . For Windows Phone 8 you need at least Windows 8. So you have to update your OS to do so.

I suggest a dual boot system as the best option, or you can install Windows 8.1 on a virtual Machine and then install Visual Studio 2013 and WP SDK in it. but it is very painful to develop like that and you will need a lot of resources in RAM and processing power. Best way if to go for a dual-boot system.